# conversion varchar to int issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query attempts to convert a `varchar` datatype to `int` -- but it's not working. Do you know why?

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, [BR]) AS dd,
    CAST([BR] AS INT) AS cc
FROM 
    [Seg].[dbo].[pro_ben]
```

I get the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3893.768' to data type int

Comment: An integer is a whole number... So you can't directly convert a decimal to whole number. You need to round that one up or down or select a different data type for the conversion

Comment: [Sure you can](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7a142122e435a7d029e9578a92bed9f) @kjmerf The issue is the value isn't a decimal, it's a string. If it was a decimal, it'd be truncated.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously your string has a decimal part, hence you cannot cast it directly to an integer.

A solution would be to first `CAST` to a floating point number, and then to an integer, like:

```
SELECT CAST( CAST([BR] AS FLOAT) AS INT) AS CC FROM [Seg].[dbo].[pro_ben]
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2098d2263007a43f10b3e1a1e85b767e)**:

```
SELECT CAST('3893.768' AS FLOAT)
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|         3893.768 |
```

```
SELECT CAST( CAST('3893.768' AS FLOAT) AS INT)
```

```
| (No column name) |
| ---------------: |
|             3893 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The value is not an integer.  This leaves you with various options:

- You could use `try_convert()` which would return `NULL`.
- You can use an intermediate data type and then convert to the final data type, but you might lose precision (under some circumstances).
- You could convert to a `numeric()` instead.

Conversion to a `numeric` ignores decimal points, but they do not cause an error:

```
SELECT convert(numeric(10,0), [BR]) as dd
FROM [Seg].[dbo].[pro_ben];
```

You can then convert to an `int` if you specifically need that type.

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
Select Round([BR],0) as dd
FROM [Seg].[dbo].[pro_ben];
```

Answer (score -1):

mmmm it appears once I change data type to float, it works.

Comment: Correct.  `int` is for whole numbers only (no decimal point).